# Comparar linhas com txt Java Android

Tags: java, android, comparação

Gostaria de criar um metodo que compare cada linha do meu text view com cada linha de um arquivo txt

aqui eu percorro o arquivo txt

por exemplo, no meu text view são exibidos as palavras

azul
verde
amarelo
verde

no meu txt eu tenho

preto
azul
verde
amarelo

gostaria que emitisse um alerta sobre o verde que nao esta no arquivo txt

implementei isso

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); // saida do textview
        BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("bd.txt")); // arquivo txt
        int linha = 1;
        String line = "";
        String line1 = "";
       while ((line1 = entrada.readLine())!= null){
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
                if (line.contains(line1) == true) {

                // o que tem no textview tem no txt


                } else if (line.contains(line1) == false) {



                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa especificar melhor como  as palavras serão escritas no seu arquivo texto e textview. Se serão todas na mesma linha ou cada uma separada por uma quebra de linha.

De qualquer forma, eu fiz uma implementação geral que funcione para os dois casos:

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); // saída do textview  
  BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bd.txt")); // arquivo txt

  String line = "";

  String coresTextView = ""; 
  String coresArquivoTexto = "";

  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    coresTextView = coresTextView + line + " ";

  while((line = entrada.readLine()) != null) 
    coresArquivoTexto = coresArquivoTexto + line + " ";

  String[] cores = coresTextView.split(" ");

  for(int i = 0; i < cores.length; i++) 
    if(coresArquivoTexto.replaceFirst(cores[i], "").equals(coresArquivoTexto)) 
      System.out.println("AVISO: " + cores[i] + " não está no arquivo texto!");
    else
      coresArquivoTexto = coresArquivoTexto.replaceFirst(cores[i], "");

  reader.close();
  entrada.close();
```

Para resolver esse problema você precisa pensar em duas listas: uma com as cores do textview e outra com as cores do seu arquivo texto.

Você vai pegar as cores do textview uma por uma e comparar com toda a lista das cores do seu arquivo texto. Se você encontrar a cor da sua lista do textview na lista de cores do arquivo texto, você pode remover a cor da lista do arquivo texto para não correr o risco de encontrar novamente caso você tenha a mesma cor duas vezes na lista de cores do textview.

Na minha implementação, eu utilizei Strings como as "listas" de cores que eu citei na explicação acima. A String **coresTextView** pega as linhas do textview e faz uma junção separada por espaços. Depois, separa todas as palavras da String por espaço e joga no vetor de Strings **cores**. Com isso, eu tenho cada cor do textview em uma posição do meu vetor de Strings **cores**.

A String **coresArquivoTexto** é uma String que junta todas as cores encontradas no arquivo texto, separando-as por espaço.

Logo após vem o laço para percorrer todas as cores encontradas no textview. Dentro do laço tem a condição que faz a comparação para ver se a cor está presento no arquivo texto:

```
if(coresArquivoTexto.replaceFirst(cores[i], "").equals(coresArquivoTexto))
```

Aqui é uma simples manipulação de String. Se a cor do vetor de String de cores do textview não estiver presente na String de cores do arquivo texto, então a função **.replaceFirst** vai retornar a String **coresArquivoTexto** sem nenhuma mudança. Com isso, nós sabemos que a cor não está presente no arquivo texto.

Agora, caso a cor do vetor de Strings de cores do textview estiver presente no arquivo texto, vamos atualizar a String **coresArquivoTexto** removendo a cor que acabamos de verificar. Fazemos isso associando a variável à função **.replaceFirst** que deve retornar a String sem a cor passada como parâmetro.

```
coresArquivoTexto = coresArquivoTexto.replaceFirst(cores[i], "");
```

E isso faz o trabalho que você quer!

Eu não sei com quantas cores e tamanhos de arquivos texto você pretende trabalhar, pode ser que talvez a variável do tipo String utilizada não suporte tantas palavras do arquivo texto ou textview que você venha a utilizar. Nesse caso, procure trocar o tipo para listas, por exemplo, ou até mesmo associar os nomes das cores a números de 1-9 e você pode ter uma String com milhares de caracteres de códigos que indicam cores.

*Obs: Nessa implementação tome cuidado com espaços nos seus arquivos texto e textview, lembre-se que a função **.split(" ")** vai dividir a String exatamente em um espaço, se você tiver mais de um espaço entre as cores dos seus arquivos, isso pode ocasionar em problemas na execução do programa*

Comment: no caso, o arquivo txt ficaria no diretorio assets??

Comment: Na pasta principal do projeto.